# Receiving TypeError on ShardIterator when Getting Records from Kinesis

Tags: amazon-kinesis

I have the following block of Python to get the records that I have placed onto a Kinesis stream and then put the records into an S3 bucket. There is a single shard for this stream.

```
# Fetching the shard iterators from the Kinesis stream
shard_iterators = []
if response and 'StreamDescription' in response:
    for shard_id in response['StreamDescription']['Shards']:
        shard_id = shard_id['ShardId']
        shard_iterator = kinesis_connection.get_shard_iterator(stream_name, shard_id, 'LATEST')
        shard_iterators.append(shard_iterator['ShardIterator'])

# Iterating over the Kinesis stream and pushing data to S3
bucket = s3_connection.get_bucket(bucket_name)
k = Key(bucket)

for shard_iterator in shard_iterators:
    while 1:
        response = kinesis_connection.get_records(shard_iterator)
        shard_iterator = response['NextShardIterator']
        if len(response['Records'])> 0:
            for res in response['Records']:
                k.key = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y/%m/%d/') + res['SequenceNumber']
                k.set_contents_from_string(res['Data'])
```

The data is initially pulled off the stream and pushed to S3, but at some point, I receive `TypeError: expected string or buffer` on the line `response = kinesis_connection.get_records(shard_iterator)`. There are many more records on the shard that should be available for me to pull. Has anyone encountered this issue before and/or does anyone have ideas on what I should try to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

That error seems likely thrown by json decoding a non-string. e.g. `None`, or int.

```
import json
json.loads(None)
...
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
   obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Which may be happening here: https://github.com/boto/boto/blob/develop/boto/kinesis/layer1.py#L705

Which would mean that the response body coming back is `None`.

That *could* be due to your shard_iterator expiring. Shard iterators only last for 5 minutes, so if you take a long time to process the current batch of records, or otherwise stalling, that may be it.
SEE: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesis/latest/APIReference/API_GetShardIterator.html

The other possibility is that its an intermittent auth/connection error, which I've seen before, and which may generate spurious exceptions, which might lead to that same boto code path?

Though if you could provide more of the stack trace and any log messages you're seeing, it would be helpful.